# Python.net C# class multiple instances class denied

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I am trying to access C# class with multiple instances of an class with Python.net).

```
import clr
import sys
sys.append({path})
clr.AddReference({project})
from TestProject import TestClass
```

But as soon as I include more than one class, it breaks and tells me 'Module not found', while it is a perfect class and builds fine.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestObject test1;
    public TestObject test2;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

So, completely my mistake. I had assumed that pythonnet could use both .NET(8) projects as .NET Frameworks (4.8) projects, but it turns out is works a lot better with the .NET Framework projects. No problems since. Hopefully this also helps someone else, because I could not find much on it online.